# Creating and modifying files inside a php library under .htpasswd protected folder (from the library itself)

Tags: php, file, security

I've got a PHP library inside a folder that is protected through .htpasswd.

To be able to change the library configuration, I've created a html/php console inside that folder too.

After properly logging in to the console through valid user/password, the console can call some php scripts (inside the library itself) that aim to create/modify some files to be able to change some of the library parameters dynamically.

Anyways, when trying to modify/create files or running chmod, i get "Operation not permitted" and "Permission denied" messages.

This is fixed if I modify a subfolder permissions to 777 (just in the one i want to modify the files), but i'm wondering if this represents a security hole.

Which is the best practice to allow the library modify some of its files without losing any security in its folder from the outside?

Comment: So, you have not permissions and it's not relative with .htpasswd

Comment: Yes... it is relative to the folder write permissions. I do have permissions if I change them to 777 in some subfolders, but i'm wondering if that represents a security hole.